# How can I use clock_gettime to calculate the total time it takes for a command

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I'm having a bit of an issue with the specifics of how to manipulate the values obtained from clock_gettime. Im looking to calculate the total running time of an executable/command.

I'm looking to print out the realtime in the format of (eg. 3.475s)
I'm almost done but am pretty sure that it wont return in the format I want. How could I do so?

```
  struct timespec tsstart, tsend;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tsstart);
  //execuatble/command executes and finishes
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tsend);
  long long realtime = (tsend.tv_sec-tsstart.tv_sec)*1000000LL + tsend.tv_usec-tsstart.tv_usec;
  printf("real: %.3lds, ", realtime);
```

Whenever I try running this, for a short period (ie. <10s), all I get is an output along the lines of

```
35273s
```

How could I change the formatting of the output to the 3d.p. precision I need ?

Comment: Hmmm, standard C has `struct timespec` "which holds an interval specified in seconds and **nanoseconds** ..." and member `long tv_nsec`.  Curious linux uses `.tv_usec`.

Comment: With `long long realtime`, I'd expect `"%.3lld"`, not `"%.3ld"`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, yeah that was one mistake I spotted as well, i prolly messed it up cause Im working with rusage simultaneously, but yes for this it would be ```.tv_nsec``` .

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica As for ```%.3ld``` yes a little bit of a type mismatch but wasnt the issue

Comment: needshelpwithcoding "little bit of a type mismatch" implies you are not compiling with all warnings enabled.  Thus you are not fully using the first productively asset available - your compiler.  Save time for yourself and, as a professional courtesy, others.

Answer (score 0):

```
  struct timespec tsstart, tsend;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tsstart);
  //execuatble/command executes and finishes
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tsend);
  float realtime = (tsend.tv_sec-tsstart.tv_sec)+(tsend.tv_nsec-tsstart.tv_nsec)/1000000000.0;
  printf("real: %.3fs, ", realtime);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To change scaled `long long` integer (`*1000000LL`) to a x.xxxxxx output

```
printf("%s%lld.%06lld", 
    realtime < 0 ? "-" : "", 
    llabs(realtime/1000000), 
    llabs(realtime%1000000));
```

---

Tricky cases include `realtime` values in the the `[-999999 ... -1]`.  Of course these values are not *expected* with the time subtraction.

If we *assume* `realtime >= 0`, then

```
printf("%lld.%06lld", 
    realtime/1000000, realtime%1000000);
```

---

To toss the lower 3 digits:

```
// Form rounded quotient of milliseconds
long long ms = realtime/1000 + (realtime%1000 >= 500);
printf("%lld.%03lld", ms/1000, ms%1000);
```